# Kotlin generics with subtypes?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I can't wrap my head around why arent subtypes working with Kotlin generics.

Assume the following simple scenario

```
class Student : Person()
open class Person
```

This works

```
fun personOrStudent : Person{
return Student()
}
```

But this doesnt

```
fun <Item:Person> personOrStudent() : Item {
return Student()
}
```

I dont understand why. Isn't the return type Item , typed as a subtype of Person ? . I believe the syntax clearly communicates that Item would be a subtype of Person .

But I get a compile time error saying expected was Person , not a student.

Does this have something to do with covariance / contravariance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining a function as parameterized we basically mean that we don't know the exact type of `Item` and that it depends on the call site. `Student` may be a valid return value from this function, but it may be not.

Consider this example:

```kotlin
class NotAStudent : Person()

personOrStudent<NotAStudent>()
```

We expect that the function returns `NotAStudent`, but implementation returned `Student`. This is why it can't compile.

In other words: `<Item: Person>` doesn't mean that `Item` is just any `Person`. It means `Item` is a very specific subtype of `Person`, but we don't know which one.

Answer (score 1):

A different way of explaining it in case it helps:

The difference is that with generics, the type that the generic represents is defined in the code that calls it. Your generic function doesn't return a `Person`. It returns whatever specific type the caller asks for. `<T: Person>` means the caller is restricted to asking for types that are Persons or subtypes of Persons.

```
open class Person
class Student : Person()
class Teacher: Person()

//...

val teacher = personOrStudent<Teacher>() // The caller is asking for a Teacher.
```

If they ask for a `Teacher`, a Student would be an invalid response.

In real-world application, I don't think there would ever be a reason to write a generic function like this, where the generic type is used solely as a return type and not by the parameters, because there's no way to determine/use the requested type if it isn't related to any of the function inputs. With `reified` types, it is possible, though, because the reified type is itself an input.