# Kotlin Generics Upper Bound

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I do not understand why this wont work .

```
open class Person
class Student : Person()

fun <T:Person> getPerson() : T {
  return Student()
}
```

I could type cast it as T , but then i'll get a warning saying "unchecked cast" .

All this doesn't make sense to me .
When I have already specified the return type to be a child of Person , and I am returning exactly that , why am I not being allowed?

Comment: The upper bound is stating the return type can be anything that is a subtype of `Person` - consider adding `class Teacher : Person()`.  So by the logic of your function its return type could either be a `Person`, `Student` or `Teacher` - but you return a `Student` which is not a `Teacher` even though they have a common parent they are incompatible - hence the error.  Casting will also promote `ClassCastException` errors - hence the warning.  The upper/lower bound return type is simply `Person`

Comment: I already answered your question 2 weeks ago and you even marked it as solved: [Kotlin generics with subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71536457/kotlin-generics-with-subtypes)

Comment: @broot well I just wasted my time explaining it ...